# Maximum Concurrent Connection of MySQL server?

Tags: connection, mysql5

For the following hardware specification, how can I estimate the maximum concurrent connection of MySQL server?

- Intel Xeon E5620 2.4GHz 12MB L3 Cache 1066MHz
- 4GB x 3 1333MHz DDR3 ECC RAM
- 300GB SAS HDD (10K rpm)
- MySQL Server 5.1 Community version
- Ubuntu Linux Server 11.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

Test with [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the purpose of estimating the maximum concurrent connection is to test whether the hardware is sufficient for certain amount of concurrent connection. We need to estimate the number of concurrent connection BEFORE purchasing the hardware.